# Resource ownership in REST API

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, restful-url

In the following scenario:

- A **User** can create **Games**.
- A **User** who creates a game is called **Owner**.
- **Games** have their own unique id globally.
- Other **Users** can join **Games** they don't own, these are called **Players**.

One would send a request to `/game/{id}` to get the Game data, which should be the same for every client, something like:

```
{
   name: 'My Game',
   sport: 'Football'
   ...
}
```

Let's say that we have to show a "Settings" link for the Game owner in the Main Game Screen. This "Settings" link can't be displayed for regular Players.

Both Player and Owner can see the Main Game Screen.

How can I verify the ownership of this resource to show different components to the users?

- I think that adding the `ownerId` to the response would be a liability since one could change the value on the client side, is that right?
- Also, adding an `isOwner` field would make it impossible to cache the response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here may lie in HATEOAS type structures. Your resource should contain a list of navigable links to other information/children/lists, etc. If 'settings' is an option for the requesting user, then a link to the settings should be returned as part of the object, otherwise no such link would exist.

Caching: This does present a problem, but it's solvable.

Comment: In this case, how would this be solvable from the caching point of view? The response becomes user-based with this approach.

Comment: The problem as stated isn't really cacheable -- you get different output depending on the user, which is why we don't usually cache data. You'd have to split this into two requests, one for the object and one for its metadata (which includes the reference to the settings). The initial dto can be cached but the user-specific data cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk about the server application and the client application. The client application contains *Main Game Screen* and should show or hide some panes depend on *something*.

The server application should provide this *something*. Cause the server application is REST it should provide some recourse. What the kind of the resource and where it should be?

```
GET /games/{gameId}/users/{userId}/something
GET /users/{userId}/games/{gameId}/something
```

It's possible to call this *something* the user's rights or permissions. Is this separate resource? Maybe, no. So you can implement the method

```
GET /games/{gameId}/users/{userId}
```

The method will return user's profile and corresponding permissions for the game with id `{gameId}` like here:

```
{
    givenNames: 'Miguel de Cervantes',
    familyName: 'Saavedra',
    totalScore: 10342,

    permissions: {
        canClose: false,
        canSetup: false,
        . . .
    }
}
```

And of course the server application should check permissions for every client's request.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I see this kind of approach, so I have a few questions about the implications of following this type of permission handling across the application: The current users' profile data can be fetched by requesting the `/users/{id}` endpoint. Would it be ok to also include user-related data in this suggested endpoint (`/games/{gameId}/users/{userId}`)?

Comment: In this case, it means that one more request would have to be made to get the user's permission, wouldn't this degrade the performance of the application? And since the `permissions` node would be a standard across the application, what would be the best way to document the different type permissions keys (`canClose`, `canSetup`...) in the documentation?

Comment: On the first question. Yes, it would be ok. Sometimes subresouces can be accessible by different paths, especially when there's relation many-to many. You have games, you have users, and you have all games of the specified user.

Comment: On the second question. The general rule is to pass as much data as possible at a time (pattern *Remote Façade*). `Permissions` is a simple non-large collection so you can just include it inside the user object. In [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) you can use `include` query parameter to pass desired optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to solve a concept issue related to resource responsability, because a resource that returns game information, shouldn't return security information like "see or not see a button".

So, I would create a specific resource to return security information like this.
In this specific security resource, for the mentioned case above, I wouldn't pass any parameter by the URL and through the authentication hash I would get user id to verify if he is a game owner returning a simple response like true or false to know if that user can see that button.

Obviously, that resource could answer much many security information about other screens and buttons.

A resource like:

```
GET /security/buttons/{buttonId}
```

And in the future:

```
GET /security/screens/{screenId}
GET /security/functionalities/{functionalityId}
GET /security/actions/{actionId}
.
.
.
```

Comment: The button was just an abstract example since I can't share the actual scenario here. The button represents "information and actions exclusively related to the **Game Owner**.

As for your answer, wouldn't that go against the [Resource concept](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) and also the [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3)?